# Any Tricks to Better Identify Disabled SSIS Elements?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Does anyone have any tricks they care to share that will help better identify disabled elements within SSIS packages?  Ideally there's some manner to adjust the text color to red or or something along those lines, but the default behavior seems significantly lacking in my mind.  I've dug through a number of options, but nothing seems to impact the display of *only* the disabled elements.

Here's an example image where 4 of the 6 elements are disabled:

[image]

As much as I'd love to fall back to consistent SSIS development practices, these packages are mainly inherited, so I'm stuck with a mixed bag of approaches to work with.

This screenshot was taken from within Visual Studio 2012, but I believe the issue exists on a number of other versions as well.

Comment: According to this bug, it has been fixed... That said, no information was given by Microsoft on the fix.: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/780973/ssis-in-vs2012-way-too-hard-to-distinguish-disabled-items-accessibility-issue

Comment: In SSIS Data Tools, both the test and the icon are shown in gray, as opposed to just the text. My assumption is that's the fix. Are there any updates available for your version of VS2012?

Comment: @RDFozz There are, but this machine is so locked down I have to bribe people for a brief window of admin rights to install stuff that doesn't come through SCCM patches.  I'll look into this.  Any other options, or is this _the one and only_?

Comment: I haven't seen anything else to date. Just moved from BIDS (SQL 2008) to SSIS Data Tools - I'm used to the entire task turning gray (which was much more obvious - no idea why anyone thought this was better).

Answer (score 2):

You could always look at the underlying XML:

```
  DTS:Disabled="True"
```